# qooxdoo When you create a custom drop down box, click the drop-down box in the form element and the drop-down box is automatically closed

Tags: qooxdoo

Go to the page and click the drop down box. When you click on the form element inside the drop-down box, the drop-down box is also closed. How to solve this problem

playground link ：tinyurl.com/y9kzfct8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is the focus of the form. You can set the `this.setKeepFocus(true)` in the constructor. When you keep `autohide(false)` you have now to handle closing, or you can set it to true but then you have to handle the focus on all children elements on the form.

Comment: Tinyurl is not working for me. Just add `this.setKeepFocus(true);` on line 10 in your Playground example.

Comment: When I click on the blank area of the page, The drop-down box cannot be automatically closed

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help of @MarkusDonhauser_twitter

selectbox.getChildControl("popup").addListener("changeVisibility", function(e) { this.setAutoHide(e.getData() !== "visible");}, this);